# How to initialize form with some parameters of model instance

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like be able to send SMS/Email notifications manually using the groups/users of a model instance. Let's say the model looks like this:

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    receiver = models.ManyToManyField(EmployeeType, related_name='memos_receiver')
```

I pass the object instance to the view:

```
path('<int:pk>/notify', NotificationView.as_view(), name='memos-notify'),
```

The form and the view are where I am having trouble. I figure I should be able to just pass the forms initial fields right there in the view:

```
class NotificationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'memos/notification_form.html'
    form_class = MemoNotificationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('overview')

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(NotificationView, self).get_initial()
        memo = Memo.objects.filter(id=id)
        initial['receiving_groups'] = memo.receiver.all()
        return initial
```

And the form looks like this:

```
class MemoNotificationForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'receiving_groups'
        ]

    receiving_groups = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

*Note: the `receiving_groups` will be the ones receiving the notification. Once the form is valid I will apply a `send_sms` method send it.

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Do I need to initialize the queryset in the form? Would appreciate it if someone could paint me a clear picture of the *why* and *how* here. Thank you!

Comment: You need to pass the queryset and not just the related manager - `initial['receiving_groups'] = memo.receiver.all()`

Comment: I knew that looked wrong. That is one issue but still get the >TypeError

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of this line,

```
memo = Memo.objects.filter(id=id)
```

Here, in your ***scope***, the **`id`** becoming [***python's built-in fucntion***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) and hence the error.
To access the URL parameter, you should use **`self.kwargs`** attribute, as below

```
class NotificationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'memos/notification_form.html'
    form_class = MemoNotificationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('overview')

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(NotificationView, self).get_initial()
        memo = Memo.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        initial['receiving_groups'] = memo.receiver.all()
        return initial
```

You can find the working example from the official Django documentaion here, [**Dynamic filtering**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

Comment: I have to give you a updoot because that handles the `TypeError` and you explained it well. Though now it is giving `KeyError at /memos/1/notify
'id'`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `self.kwargs['pk']` (check my updated answer)

Comment: I am going to call this the correct answer to the specific question though I have other errors to deal with. Thanks and good job!